# Не приходят сообщения через SimpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend

Tags: spring, post, spring-websocket

Мне нужно отправлять POST запрос и потом перенаправлять полученный текст для отправки через сокеты на фронт. Я использую convertAndSend, но сообщения не доходят

Мой класс:

```java
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    SimpMessagingTemplate template;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/match/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void test(@RequestBody String input, @PathVariable("id") String id){
        template.convertAndSend("/topic/message", new ErrorDTO(id));
    }

    @SendTo("/topic/message")
    public void broadcastMessage(@Payload ErrorDTO errorDTO){
        System.out.println(errorDTO);
    }
}
```

Мой конфиг:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOriginPatterns("*");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }
}
```

ErrorDTO:

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
public class ErrorDTO {

    private String message;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как выяснилось, я пытался реализовать неправильную логику, так как `SimpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend` отправляет данные на клиент, который слушает этот сокет по указанному адресу